# How can I attach a datalist to input textbox dynamically?

Tags: javascript, datalist

I am creating input text boxes dynamically in my javascript. For example, there is a single textbox at first. When the user clicks a + button a new text box gets added. Now, I want to attach a datalist to the next textbox. I will be generating the datalist also dynamically based on some other user selection. All the examples that I see of datalist usage are like

But I wanted to do something like:
    newTextBox = document.createElement("input");
    newList = document.createElement("datalist");
    newTextBox.list= newList;
    newList.options[0] = "choice1";
    newList.options[1] = "choice2";
.....
....

Is this possible? How can I do this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: In the previous post I had written - "All the examples that I see of datalist usage are like" but the example I typed did not go out. Here it is.

Comment: <input list="cars">
<datalist id="cars">
<option value="ford">
<option value="toyota">
<option value="porsche">
</datalist>
Unfortunately this does not help me because all the actions - creation, attachment of list to input tag, and population of list must be dynamic for my use-case.

Answer (score 0):

Load the list from your database or server, using ajax

```
$('#list-container').load("/lists/somelist.html", function() {
    alert("list loaded");
});
```

See: [.load() | jQuery API Docs](http://api.jquery.com/load/)

---

## Example:

```
<a id="list1-link">Show list 1</a>
<div id="list1-container" style="display:none;"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">
$("#list1-link").on("mouseover", function() {
    var pos = $(this).position();
    var width = $(this).outerWidth();
    $("#list1-container").load("/lists/list1.html", function() {
        $(this).css({
            position: "absolute",
            top: pos.top + "px",
            left: (pos.left + width) + "px"
        }).fadeIn();
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. 2 issues - and I should probably have been clearer in my earlier question, so excuse me if so. 1st - how to attach the datalist to the "input" element? I am not able to understand how loading using ajax will solve this. 2nd - is it possible to show in javascript? My application is almost done, and if possible I do not want to drag a new framework (like ajax) into it at this time. Thank you so much

Comment: You're probably making your life very difficult using pure javascript. Besides, there are so many websites using jQuery that your browser probably cached the script anyway, so if you use the google CDN your users shouldn't experience any "drag" or extra loading time.

Comment: As for attaching the datalist, you do it the same way as in the example I gave you, except instead of using a DIV element you reference the ID of your datalist element.

Comment: Sorry if I am slow & repeating the same question without understanding the answer. When I was trying to transfer this to script, somehow it still didn't seem to give me the answer. You have suggested:
<a id="list1-link">Show list 1</a>
<div id="list1-container" style="display:none;"></div>
But I am creating these dynamically using document.createElement("datalist") & document.createElement("input") methods. Further complication is Chrome browser doesn't seem to handle document.getElementById(myId) for dynamic created objects if I assign id like --- object.id = myId

Comment: What's the problem if you are creating them dynamically? The jQuery .on() method will handle the event delegation for you, whether the element exists at page load or is created later.